# Set Foreign Key to Null in One to Many Relationship in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship

My question is related to Laravel 5.6. I have `Post` and `Category` models. They have one-to-many relationship, with `category_id` as foreign key in `posts` table. The `category_id` is nullable field

```
//Post Model
class Post extends Model
{
   public function category()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id', 'id');
   }
}

//Category Model
class Category extends Model
{
   public function posts()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'category_id', 'id');
   }
}
```

My question is, If I delete a category. How do I set `category_id` to null for all the associated posts in `posts` table ?

I know laravel provide `dissociate` method, but I think it is for `belongsTo` relationship. Is there something similar to below?

```
$category::find($id);    
$category->posts()->dissociate(); //set all foreign key(category_id) to null in posts table
$category->delete();
```

Comment: I'm no Laravel expert - but wouldn't you do this in the database instead? With a foreign key `ON DELETE SET NULL` type thing...

Comment: Thanks, this is really good suggestion, I will look into it more. But I am still looking to it in laravel way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to take care of this yourself, let the foreign key handle it (as suggested by CD001):

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    [...]
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')
      ->onDelete('set null');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Agree this is better solution. I was trying too much unnecessarily. This is what I was thinking of doing, but your solution is much better and cleaner.
`$category = Category::find($id);
      $posts = $category>posts();
            foreach( $posts as $post) {
                $post->category()->dissociate();
                $post->save();
           }
`